# how to supply credentials for Basic or Digest authentication in Apache HttpClient + Axis2

Tags: authentication, httpclient, apache-axis, credentials

I am working with a web service client which uses Axis2 1.6.1. I need to supply credentials for Basic or Digest authentication to the server. I am working with Axis2 classes, not HttpClient directly. I have searched the web and read some of the Axis2 source code, but I haven't figured out how to supply the credentials. Can anyone briefly explain it or give a suitable link?

I gather that credentials are associated with the HttpClient class in Apache HttpClient. I guess that if I could retrieve a reference to the HttpClient object used by Axis2, I could call HttpClient methods to assign the credentials. Perhaps someone knows how to do that?

Thanks in advance for any light you can shed on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First create an instance of the [HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/transport/http/HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator.html) class and set the username and password.

```
HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator
   auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
auth.setUsername("username");
auth.setPassword("password");
```

You may also want to set the host, port and realm at this point, if you want to limit the scope of the authentication for security reasons.

Next create an instances of the [Options](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/Options.html) class and set the [HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/transport/http/HTTPConstants.html#AUTHENTICATE) property with your authenticator.

```
Options options = new Options();
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);
```

This is where you would also usually set your EndpointReference and any other options that you required.

Finally you can create your [ServiceClient](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/ServiceClient.html) object and call *setOptions* to pass in the options you have just created.